# How to parse Value in OrderedDict and then sort it?

Tags: python, sorting, ordereddictionary

I have a multidimensional OrderedDict and the value from the key "stampdate" is a string and i have to parse it in a datetime-format and then i want to sort it.

#############################################################

Here is my current Ordered Dict:

```
[
OrderedDict(
    [
        ("id", 56),
        ("werkzeug", 1006),
        ("stampdate", "2021-12-12T10:48:19.735532"),
        ("aktivstatus", "1"),
    ]
),
OrderedDict(
    [
        ("id", 57),
        ("werkzeug", 1006),
        ("stampdate", "2021-12-15T10:49:33.876611"),
        ("aktivstatus", "1"),
    ]
),
OrderedDict(
    [
        ("id", 60),
        ("werkzeug", 1006),
        ("stampdate", "2021-12-12T13:42:46.216805"),
        ("aktivstatus", "1"),
    ]
),
OrderedDict(
    [
        ("id", 230),
        ("werkzeug", 1006),
        ("stampdate", "2022-01-11T21:40:39.489662"),
        ("aktivstatus", "1"),
    ]
),
]
```

The Result should look like this way:

```
[
OrderedDict(
    [
        ("id", 56),
        ("werkzeug", 1006),
        ("stampdate", "2021-12-12T10:48:19.735532"),
        ("aktivstatus", "1"),
    ]
),

OrderedDict(
    [
        ("id", 60),
        ("werkzeug", 1006),
        ("stampdate", "2021-12-12T13:42:46.216805"),
        ("aktivstatus", "1"),
    ]
),

OrderedDict(
    [
        ("id", 57),
        ("werkzeug", 1006),
        ("stampdate", "2021-12-15T10:49:33.876611"),
        ("aktivstatus", "1"),
    ]
),
OrderedDict(
    [
        ("id", 230),
        ("werkzeug", 1006),
        ("stampdate", "2022-01-11T21:40:39.489662"),
        ("aktivstatus", "1"),
    ]
),
]
```

Comment: That looks like a list of OrderedDict of a list of tuples... Is it necessary to have so many nested iterable types?

Comment: If you are using python version 3.7 or above, you can use the built-in ```dict```, becouse from this version they change part of the internal implementation of dicts, so now it is ensured that the iteration order will be the same as the insertion order.

Comment: @alexpdev is right.  You have a list, not an OrderedDict.  Do `data.sort( key=lambda k: k['id'] )` to get these in order by id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> sorted(list_of_odered_dicts,key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['stampdate'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'))
[OrderedDict([('id', 56), ('werkzeug', 1006), ('stampdate', '2021-12-12T10:48:19.735532'), ('aktivstatus', '1')]), OrderedDict([('id', 60), ('werkzeug', 1006), ('stampdate', '2021-12-12T13:42:46.216805'), ('aktivstatus', '1')]), OrderedDict([('id', 57), ('werkzeug', 1006), ('stampdate', '2021-12-15T10:49:33.876611'), ('aktivstatus', '1')]), OrderedDict([('id', 230), ('werkzeug', 1006), ('stampdate', '2022-01-11T21:40:39.489662'), ('aktivstatus', '1')])]
```